# Query to MS CRM Database does not return results

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a query that get accounts for a business unit based on a set criteria. When using one business unit, the query works find and brings back the results. Running the same code, changing only the business unit, running with a different business unit, the result come back empty.

If I run this query in HeidiSQL it works for both business units.

Another feature to this problem is in the bad business unit, a Customer Care Rep can not get the results, yet Customer Care Supervisor can. In the good business unit, both can get the results.

This leads me to think there is a problem with security. However I have compared both business units teams and roles and they match.

Is there something else, that I am overlooking that could stop a team from getting data from the database.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://andrewbschultz.com/2011/08/09/business-units-bus-and-security-roles-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-solution-exports/

> Without BUs, the following security configurations would be possible:

1. > A user could have access to his own CRM records
2. > A user could have access to all CRM records

> With BUs, the following additional security
>   configurations are possible:

1. > A user can have access to all records owned by users in his business
   >   unit
2. > A user can have access to all records owned by users in his own
   >   and any child business units

My understanding is that if the records are owned by a user from BU1, then users in BU2 won't be able to access them until ownership is transfered to a user in BU2. 
In order to have users in both BUs access the same records, you have to share all of them with at least one (or maybe all) users in BU2.

Comment: I've updated the question. The query is changed to get the business unit's record.